# Protecting/securing a single Mac OS X partition (dual-boot setup)

Tags: macos, mac, security, partitioning, encryption

I want to know how to protect a specific Mac OS X 10.7 partition which is installed on a dual-boot machine.

I do not need anything too powerful or secure, but I have two Mac partitions on the same machine, one of which I would prefer had some kind of security layer/protection.  More specifically, if I wanted to protect "partition A", I want to prevent logging into "partition B" and browsing through and/or modifying the contents of "partition A".

I do not know if some kind of password protection would suffice or if I actually need encryption of some or all of the contents of "partition A" (or perhaps complete encryption of the entire hard drive, "partition A" + "partition B").  If it would simplify my configuration, I would not require that "partition A" were protected from the scenario in which some external drive were used to boot into some other OS (ex. Linux) in order to snoop around "partition A".  I am mainly concerned about protecting "partition A" from "partition B".

According to my brief research, there seems to be multiple approaches to solving this general problem.  Encryption apparently adds performance overhead, unfortunately, so I will almost certainly avoid that, even if it is my only option.  I am looking for a convenient, light security solution.  Again, my security demands are pretty lax.

Comment: Do the parties you want to keep out of partition A have admin privileges in either of the dual-boot environments?

Comment: They would have admin privileges in both environments, yes.

Comment: Your choices for blocking access under Mac OS are file permissions and encryption.  An admin user can disable use of file permissions on a volume with a mouse click in Finder, so that leaves encryption.